# Is there a reason I cannot view the data within the Organization_Usage Schema in the Snowflake DB using the account admin role?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a reason I cannot view the data within the Organization_Usage Schema in the Snowflake DB using the account admin role? Whenever I try to look at the data in the Organization_Usage Schema using the Accountadmin role the secured view is just empty. I have used my account admin role on a different instance and I could view this data and I was able to grant imported priveleges to another role to use for analytics, but for some reason in our other instance those views are just not populated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The reason is that “The ORGANIZATION_USAGE schema is only available from an account that has the ORGADMIN role enabled (i.e. the ORGADMIN account).”, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/organization-usage)

Comment: That's what I thought, but on the instance we were able to do it on previously we didn't have an orgadmin account either

Comment: What i  believe you should access the views in SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATIO_USAGE schema from ORGADMIN account (separate SNOWFLAKE account created when ORGADMIN is enabled) using ACCOUNTADMIN role.

Comment: @Lbowler I don’t really understand your last comment. When you say instance I assume you mean account (an account is what you log into I.e. different accounts have different URLs)? So what do you mean by “we didn't have an orgadmin account”? Do you mean that in that account you didn’t have the ORGADMIN role enabled and weren’t using that role when you queried the data?